# How do I remove a variable with just its value

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a game similar to this one, https://gyazo.com/8d8dff02a09d27ba28ed303979f64894 its called Farkle! How it works is, you roll a dice, if you roll a 1 and get 100 points (or another die gives you points) That die is taken away until you Farkle, change turns or you win the game. But I'm not sure how to temporarily take the dice away based on its value after rolling it. Can someone please tell me the method for removing a variable based on its value?

```
from random import randint
score1 = 0
def dices():
    score1 = 0
    a = 0
    dice1 = randint(1, 6)
    dice2 = randint(1, 6)
    dice3 = randint(1, 6)
    dice4 = randint(1, 6)
    dice5 = randint(1, 6)
    dice6 = randint(1, 6)
    rolled_dice = [dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4, dice5, dice6]
    one_count = rolled_dice.count(1)
    a = [0, 100, 200, 300, 1000, 2000, 300][one_count]
    two_count = rolled_dice.count(2)
    score1 += a
    a = [0, 0, 0, 200, 1000, 2000, 3000][two_count]
    score1 += a
    three_count = rolled_dice.count(3)
    a = [0, 0, 0, 300, 1000, 2000, 3000][three_count]
    score1 += a
    four_count = rolled_dice.count(4)
    a = [0, 0, 0, 400, 1000, 2000, 3000][four_count]
    score1 += a
    five_count = rolled_dice.count(5)
    a = [0, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 2000, 3000][five_count]
    score1 += a
    six_count = rolled_dice.count(6)
    a = [0, 0, 0, 600, 1000, 2000, 3000][six_count]
    score1 += a

    print(score1)
    if score1 == 0:
        print("Farkle!")
    print(rolled_dice)

dices()
```

Comment: Can you limit the code to the problem you are facing? It would help a lot.

Comment: What result are you getting and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm just trying to get it so if a certain group of dice or just one dice contributes to giving points to remove those dice and only roll the remaining dice the next roll.

Answer (score 0):

Let's think of it as we would in real life. If you roll dices and want to keep some results, you can mark them down or put them aside until you rolled the others. You *do not throw them away* since the result is still of importance.

The same happens when coding, you do not want to throw away values that you might later need. Instead you write them down somewhere safe until you need them.

You could achieve that by keeping the results of your dices in a `list` and writing a `reroll` function that only rerolls some dices, but not all.

```
import random

def reroll(dices, *pos):
    for x in pos:
        dices[x] = random.randint(1, 6)

# This creates a list with 6 dices result in it
dices = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(6)]
print(dices)  # [1, 5, 3, 6, 6, 5]

# We now only want to reroll the first and third dices
reroll(dices, 0, 2)
print(dices)  # [4, 5, 1, 6, 6, 5]
```

An even better solution that does not *mutate* your data, i.e. that allows you to keep the previous result when you reroll, would be to make `reroll` return a new list of values where it rerolled only some dices.

```
import random, copy

def reroll(dices, *pos):
    dices = copy.copy(dices)
    for x in pos:
        dices[x] = random.randint(1, 6)
    return dices

dices = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(6)]

# reroll returns a new list of values
new_dices = reroll(dices, 0, 2)

print(dices)      # [6, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3]
print(new_dices)  # [1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3]
```